# What's an orphan wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, orphaned-wiki

I created a tag wiki for the [mixed-content](/questions/tagged/mixed-content) tag on SO.  Later I saw I had earned two rep points for [orphan wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12665407/revisions).  When I click on the link I get sent to a revisions page, but am not sure what I am supposed to do.

What do I need to do, if anything?

Comment: I got curious about these, so I wrote [a SEDE query to retrieve them all](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1445382/all-orphan-tag-wikis-excerpts). Note that because the wikis are orphaned, they have no tag associated with them, which definitely makes categorizing/ sorting through them a challenge.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Orphan wikis are wikis for tags that no longer exist. You got the two rep points for an accepted edit suggestion; all suggested edits [work this way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work). Typically the title of of the [example](/questions/tagged/example) wiki post is "example wiki", but if the tag doesn't exist the system just titles it "orphan wiki" instead, so that's what you see in your rep list

You don't need to do anything. Orphan wikis are kept around because moderators can see a list of them and merge them into other tags as needed