# Removing my proposed tag left dead ends in my profile pages. How can I tell what happened?

Tags: support, tags

I am a bit confused about what happened to a [c#-excel](/questions/tagged/c%23-excel) tag I proposed yesterday. Please, do not judge on the usefulness of the tag (*off-topic. could possibly be another meta question*)

In my profile page, when I go to my yesterdays [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/mehow?tab=reputation) there is a [**tag-wiki**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18380779) position, but it leads to *Page is not Found* which makes it hard for me to identify what it actually is. (*I think it's the proposal of the tag*)

Today, when I look at the [summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/mehow?tab=summary) of my profile I see an [*orphan wiki*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18380779/revisions)  : [image: orphan wiki]

Unfortunately, it is **not** perfectly clear to me what an *orphan wiki* means based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148926/whats-an-orphan-wiki) answer. I would appreciate if someone reworded that for me.

There are no results returned when I am searching for [c#-excel](/questions/tagged/c%23-excel) tag on the [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/) page

There is my [suggested-edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2773166) under my activity tab in my profile which seems to be approved, however it seems like an unfinished sentence

[image: unfinished sentence] on what?

What happened to [c#-excel](/questions/tagged/c%23-excel) tag? Did it get declined/removed?

Comment: The tag was removed from whatever questions you tried to put it on, and was subsequently deleted from the system. I do agree the suggested edits info is a bit lacking in this case.

Comment: Do you remember a question that had that tag?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18380656/revisions @bart - btw I agree with removing it. Doesn't make much sense - are we going to create [C++-pointers], [JavaScript-HTML], [python-snakes-and-ladders], ...?

Comment: Ha, I was looking for another suspect @Mat. :) But yeah. That explains it. And I also don't see the point of the tag.

Comment: As I said *please do not judge the usefulness of the tag*. I can explain that in a new meta question.

Comment: Meh, not necessary. Not a good tag. But yeah, when tags end up being removed, they get cleaned up automatically. See ["What happens to Zombie tags"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags)

Comment: @Bart good link. Does it mean that since this was a new tag and was not used in any other question it automatically got removed from the system? What about the 24 hour time frame which hasn't been reached yet?

Comment: @mehow The clean up runs once a day afaik. There is no "24 hours from now" concept there. And new or not doesn't really matter.

Comment: 03:00UTC is the time I keep seeing bandied about for deleting unused tags.

Comment: It looks like your actual question is "Hey, so this tag I created got removed and all traces of it on my profile just create a mystery, what gives?"  Right?  I'm actually kinda shocked that @Mat says someone else nuked it, as I was *sure* I would have done it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag itself was removed from the question it was placed on. After a while that no one uses the tag, it gets automatically deleted.

As such, the tag wiki suggestion, while approved, has become **orphaned**.