# How are tag wiki entries deleted

Tags: support, tag-wiki

While reviewing suggested edits, I can across one for [pyython](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pyython/info) which, as the tag wiki currently states, is clearly the result of a typo.  There are no questions tagged with this, and the tag edit was approved nullifying my attempt to disapprove it.  Neither is there any way to flag the edit for moderator attention.

Is there a way for this to be removed, and if so, could somebody with sufficient power do so?

Comment: If the tag has no questions associated with it, it'll _self-destruct_ in some time.

Comment: And of course it was a suggested edit... I hate when people do that... I hate even more that reviewers approve that crap...

Comment: The wiki will become [orphan wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148926/whats-an-orphan-wiki) and if the same tag will be created again in the future, it will get new ID and new wiki, the existing one will stay orphan. Bottom line, let it be. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure if that's still true - [Do not expire single-use tags that have a tag wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki) is marked completed

Comment: @codes don't think it's relevant, the request was for tags having single question. This one here is about tags with 0 questions.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Right. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be "removed" by making it a synonym of [python](/questions/tagged/python). If someone with 2500+ reputation and a score of 5+ in [python](/questions/tagged/python) wants to synonymize it, go ahead. However, because there are no questions that are tagged with it, it will automatically remove itself by <strike>six to eight weeks</strike> 3:00 am UTC when the [tag-related processes run](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213996/238586). It does not merit mod/cm/dev [burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120642/238586).

Comment: The tag will be auto-destroyed at 03:00 UTC when the tag processes run.