# Why isn't the reputation gained for editing a tag wiki refunded if the tag is burned?

Tags: feature-request, support, reputation, suggested-edits, tag-wiki-excerpt

I suggested a tag excerpt edit that got approved.  But later, the tag was burned and the wiki "orphaned".  Instead of getting a `-2` in my reputation, the rep stayed and the link led to a [`404` error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359785).  Why is this?  The reputation gained for an approved edit on a deleted post is refunded, so why not on a tag wiki or excerpt?

#### An idea

To prevent dead links in your profile/reputation tab, why not simply have the Community user remove the orphaned wikis like it [removes dead questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)  It would prevent the dead ends, like I said.  It would also be more consistent with the deleted questions/answers suggested-edit rep refund.

Comment: Because tag wikis are never deleted.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog Then Community should remove them like it does RemoveDeadQuestions.

Comment: Is this it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bullets reviewed here:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/359785/revisions click on: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148926/whats-an-orphan-wiki - the notification should lead to the first or second link, not to a deleted question featuring the tag.

Answer (score 1):

From experience I conclude that rules for keeping rep from tag-wiki edits and post edits, are the same as for Q&A posts.

If the post was visible for 2 months your edit was useful to readers and you keep the rep. (In terms of votes keeping the rep requires a score greater than 3 on the post.)

There is some justice to this since copy-editors under the 2k rep threshold will probably take some time to realize certain posts are bound for deletion, which does not render their edits invaluable for the duration of their visibility.

Sources:

[*"Reputation and Historical Archives"*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/)

[*"What else should I know about deleted posts?"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221)

Comment: If I am not mistaken the rule of keeping the +2 rep is not mentioned in the linked canonical post. If that is the case I would suggest clarifying the issue and including the information. (I tried searching for this info and was unable to find it.)

Comment: Tag wikis and excerpts are simply not deleted in the first place, thus not triggering a reversal for a removal. That's why the question suggests having the Community user delete them. It has nothing to do with the age of the wiki.

Comment: @animuson it has the +2 issue in common and I thought it was worth mentioning since I haven't seen it explained in canonical posts.