# Add explanatory link/guidance to the sidebar of the "orphan wikis" mod tool page

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, help-text, orphaned-wiki

*(Context: I just became a moderator in the [elementary OS Stack Exchange site](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com), and am learning the ropes.)*

The sidebar of the `/admin/orphan-wikis` moderation page shows a generic text that simply says:

> This lists all tag wikis that are orphan. Merging tags may create them.

I find that to be quite cryptic unless you already know what these are, and I think it would be helpful if it included a link to a resource, such as this MSE post: [What's an orphan wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148926/whats-an-orphan-wiki)